# Article and plural for a title of a section

Tags: phrases

Which one of the following titles is better?

> (1) The Specifying of the Planning Horizon
>   (2) Specifying of the Planning Horizon
>   (3) Specifying of Planning Horizons

The context is : a planner works in a cyclic way; for each planning cycle, it needs to specify a planning horizon according to the situation at the start of the planning cycle. In the corresponding section, the author would like to introduce how the planner specifies the planning horizon each time.

Thanks!

Comment: How about **Specification of the planning horizons?**

Comment: @LasciviousGrace : Thanks for your advice. I am afraid that "specification" gives an impression that the section would introduce the properties of the planning horizon(e.g., shape), rather than "how to specify it". How do you think about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The Specifying of the Planning Horizon" sounds like a sequel to the Lord of the Rings. I'd avoid "The X of the Y". As for the other two, you can drop the "of" to place the emphasis on the **process** of specifying the horizon rather than the **specification** itself.

I think @Lascivious is right to suggest a noun form of "specify", but I think you also need to consider whether a plural of "planning horizon" is needed at all (I don't think it is).

So:

> Specification of the Planning Horizon

or

> Specifying the Planning Horizon

You could also throw in a "How To" on the latter for clarification:

> How To Specify the Planning Horizon

Comment: So, **specification** can also mean the **process of specifying**?  Besides, we should avoid **the X of the Y** only in a title or we should avoid that phrase in all the writings?

Comment: Oh, "The X of the Y" is completely grammatically fine, I just think it sounds a bit too grandiose.

Comment: And yes, <b>specification</b> can refer to either the process or the result, which is ambiguous. But I'm not sure there's a way around that; it'll be clear from context that you mean the <b>process</b>.

Answer (score 0):

> Specifying the Planning Horizon.

The reason the title

> The Specifying of the Planning Horizon

sounds wrong is that you're using *"specifying"* as a noun, and there is already a noun form of the word: *"specification"*. This is like retitling the movie *"The Paper Chase"* as *"The Chasing of the Paper"*. It's grammatical, but non-idiomatic. We don't generally use gerunds as nouns when there's a good noun form of the word already.

The reason the title

> Specifying of the Planning Horizon

sounds wrong is that as a verb, *specify* doesn't take ***of***. You say *"he specified California wine"*, not *"he specified of California wine"*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation for the choice between the gerund and the noun form word.